# SAS lag function no identifying missing values

Tags: sas, lag

I have this code where I want to identify lines with missing values and then replace a variable with the previous value of the variable (since that variable will always be blank too)

```
   DATA qfr_channel_split_FY16_SEPT1;
    set qfr_channel_split_FY16_SEPT;
    if order_count=. then do;
    avg_yr1_gm=lag1(avg_yr1_gm);
    avg_yr2_gm=lag1(avg_yr2_gm);
    avg_yr3_gm=lag1(avg_yr3_gm);
    avg_yr4_gm=lag1(avg_yr4_gm);
    avg_yr5_gm=lag1(avg_yr5_gm);
end;
    run;
```

It does nothing. It's not a problem with the =.

I have also tried outputting to a different variable name.

I suspect it's something lacking in my understanding of how the lag function works.

Anyone know why the above wouldn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lag function doesn't work in SAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484728/lag-function-doesnt-work-in-sas)

Answer (score 0):

first define the lagged variable and then do the compare to missing and replace if so.

```
data want;
set have;

lagged=lag(var);

if var=. then var=lagged;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer this with the coalesce function

```
data zeroed (drop=&var. rename=(try=&var.));
set live_sorted;
orig=&var.;
try=coalesce(&var.,lag1(&var.),lag2(&var.),lag3(&var.),lag4(&var.));
run;
```

This automatically identifies whether a variable is blank and takes the nearest lag (up to 4 as I specified above)