# SAS: Why can't you use lag in an if-else statement?

Tags: sas

I was just messing around with SAS, and decided to run this simple program.

```
data gnp_growth (keep=date gnp growth);
    attrib growth length=8 format=percent8.2;
    set sashelp.gnp;
    ans = (_n_ = 1);
    put _n_=  ', ' ans=;
    if ans then growth = .;
    else growth = log(gnp/lag(gnp));
run;



My log:
        _N_=1 , ans=1
        _N_=2 , ans=0
        ...
        _N_=126 , ans=0
```

How ever my output is oddly

[image]

However, if I were to change this a little bit I get my desired output. I am not sure what is going on here. **Anyone know why SAS is behaving this way?** Thanks in advance

```
data gnp_growth (keep=date gnp growth);
    attrib growth length=8 format=percent8.2;
    set sashelp.gnp;
    ans = (_n_ = 1);
    put _n_=  ', ' ans=;
    lag_gnp = lag(gnp);
    if ans then growth = .;
    else growth = log(gnp/lag_gnp);
run;
proc print data=gnp_growth; run;
```

[image]

Comment: This is a well documented 'problem' in using the LAG function. http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/01/03/pitfalls-of-the-lag-function/

Comment: http://support.sas.com/kb/24/665.html

Comment: http://www.lexjansen.com/search/searchresults.php?q=Lag%20functiom

Comment: Here's a good paper that details how `lag` works and more recent alternatives to conditional processing using `ifc` or `ifn`
http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug07/cc/cc33.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other answers to this question already on StackOverflow, but to sum up:

The `lag` functions work as if they internally record the values that are passed to them in a queue-type structure, and return the value that is `n` items back in the queue (1 item back, in the case of the plain `lag()` function, but you can also call `lag2()`, `lag3()`, etc). If you make the call to `lag()` conditional, the values from some observations never get passed into the queue, causing the issue you saw.

This is described in more details here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0l66p5oqex1f2n1quuopdvtcjqb.htm

Answer (score 1):

Why did you execute the LAG() function inside of conditional? That will totally disrupt the stream of values that it needs to work.
See this quesiton for full description: [lag function doesn't work in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484728/lag-function-doesnt-work-in-sas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Try this instead.

```
lag_gnp=lag(gnp);
if ans then growth = .;
else growth = log(gnp/lag_gnp);
```

Comment: I see that this works, but I don't understand why? What is wrong with calling a function in the else statement?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the stream of values that it needs to work?

Comment: The lag functions work as if they internally record the values that are passed to them in a queue-type structure, and return the value that is 'n' items back in the queue (1 item back, in the case of the plain lag() function, but you can also call lag2(), lag3(), etc). If you make the call to lag() conditional, the values from some observations never get passed into the queue, causing the issue you saw.

Comment: @ChrisLong Thanks! This is what I wanted to know. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @JimmyJackson Perhaps if you'd read the link you've been provided a few times, you would've had that information already?

Comment: @Joe True! Yet, ChrisLong answered the question more accurately in 78 words than in the thousands of words used in the suggested links. I see now that this is a duplicate, but Chris's answer is better than the others. I don't regret asking the question. Also, I would like to point out that the Lag function is working just fine (indeed, I supplied a demonstration that it is working fine), it is the behavior in the if-else statement that I didn't understand. So, if the suggested link is the preferred thread, then maybe the title should be reconsidered; just a suggestion.

Comment: @JimmyJackson I agree that this question is better at getting straight to the main confusion that users have with understanding the way LAG() works than the suggested duplicate.